# Is it possible to read and write to a file that's not on the project folder with node?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created a personal application to keep track of the books I want to read and the books I have read. For simplicity, I have a file in named `wishlist.txt` I want to read it and add to it with node.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('wishlist.txt','utf8').toString();
```

That works fine.

I've been using the app for a month and I'm fed up of the fact that I need to run the server every time I need to use this application.

So I thought to put the project in heroku but keep the `wishlist.txt` in my computer. So if you view the site, you'll see a broken application, but when I view the site, I'll be able to work with it.

To test, I tried moving the `wishlist.txt` to the desktop and now I get this error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir`

So is it possible to have the app online, and have it read my local files?

I've use `wishlist.txt` for simplicity, In reality the app is scanning from all my ebooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was possible just like that it would have been a serious security hole. (any heroku app can scan your local drive any time?)

The way I see it you have 3 choices:

1. If you want to do such a thing you will have to create some kind of a file server on your computer and change your application code to fetch the data from this server.
2. If you only need your app locally you can just run it as a service on your local machine and make sure it will start after reboot. (Instead of deploying to heroku).
3. It's possible though to upload files to heroku, just add it to your source code and it will be accessible, but of course if you will add any new book to your hard drive you will have to add it to your source code and redeploy.

If you need any further details on any of the above, just comment.

Comment: You're right about security thing, I just like this app so much, it was wishful thinking in my part. Your second choice sounds perfect. How would I do that? **would that mean I wouldn't need to have the terminal open wish `node server.js`**

Comment: Yes, you are now running as a process, when you will use it as a service it will just run in the background. There are plenty of options on how to do it, just look for "node as a service" depanding on your operation system. (E.g. forever, node-windows..) if you find this answer helpful please mark it as the right one :)

Comment: forever kept coming up in my research before, so I'll try that. Last thing, would using forever mean that the  app will start even after a reboot? Thanks

Comment: Sure, which operation system you are using?

Comment: I'm on mac, os x el capitan

Comment: Then have a look on forever / node-mac.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concern, yes. All you need to do is to first locate the location of the file through src code, assign it to a variable and put the varaible on the read file sync.

Comment: I can't the the correct location at all. Do you know how?

Comment: first go to the actual file and click properties. copy the file location then paste it on src then add \wishlist.text at the end of it.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work on node though, I thought someone knew some round-about hack

Comment: have you tried to change backslash to slash or vice versa?